# Как пропустить итерацию цикла for python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ос

Есть вот такой код:

```
import os


dir = os.listdir()
for i in range(len(dir)):
    try:
        os.chdir(dir[i])
        print(os.listdir())
    except:
        continue
```

Если это не директория, то происходит ошибка и мы пропускаем итерацию цикла, но у меня цикл просто пропускается, подскажите что не так

Comment: Какое исключение вам нужно проигнорировать?

Comment: Лучше не называйте переменные именами встроенных функций (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir). Вы можете проверять является ли это папкой через https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir. Но я бы рекомендовал использовать модуль https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Comment: А зачем вы делаете `chdir`, вы можете указать интересующий каталог параметром `listdir`. А так вы зашли в подкаталог через `chdir`, вам же потом обратно нужно выйти на уровень выше, а вы этого не делаете. Один раз сработает, а дальше ошибки будут.

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо, туплю с утра)